# Exclude/hide some values in Listbox of Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

In my **Qlikview** dashboard I have an Employee **Listbox** where I want to display those employees which got benefit in last 30 days,basically benefit amount should greater than $ 0.00.

I don't find any option in to hide such records in Listbox property, I don't want to remove those employees from main dataset because they have important facts like deductions, taxes..etc.

Comment: Stefan's answer is a good one, but making calculated list boxes in most cases lead to unwanted results in other parts of the module...best practice is to create another Field, ie  "Employees_with_benefits" and use that as needed...

Answer (score 2):

There is no option in general for this. Because the list box is just a list of values and you need to tell Qv how to aggregate and filter the values.

If you go to listbox properties and list the field options you will see the `<Expression>` option:

[image]

This will allow you to tell QV which records to show. You can use this area to enter any kind of expressions. Below are two options:

- using `if` statement: `= if( aggr( sum( Benefit ), EmployeeId ) > 30, EmployeeId )`
- using  `set analysis`: `= aggr( only( {< EmployeeId = {"= aggr( sum( Benefit ), EmployeeId ) > 30 "}>} EmployeeId ), EmployeeId )`

Both of these will filter the `EmployeeId` and show only these values for which `sum( Benefit )` is greater than 30

To see it in action use [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjGsOE_3VoOUWE5bWFaS05MRk0/view?usp=sharing) to download sample qvw file.